# 59 s for just simple select command

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select  count(*) from num;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  9918530 |
+----------+
1 row in set (59.18 sec)
```

It is horrible, 59.18 sec for just a simple select command!
How to improve MySQL performance in my windows10?

Comment: Add index by any non-null field. The best way - primary.

Comment: @Akina - That will have no impact.

Answer (score 1):

With `ENGINE=InnoDB`, the entire table must be scanned to perform the count.  Actually, any index can be used, and the Optimizer picks the smallest index (or the `PRIMARY KEY` if no secondary indexes exist.

If the table (or index) is not currently cached in the buffer_pool, then the query will take longer because of all the I/O necessary.

The reason for having to touch all the rows is that there could be other connections adding/deleting rows during the count, and InnoDB is obligated to provide the answer that is compatible with various transactional integrity requirements.  (Your Question has been asked many times; other Answers may provide more details.)